# Is there a bitscan forward/reverse in CUDA

Tags: cuda

Slight odd situation I had but I wish to use the BSF/BSR instruction inside CUDA. Just wondering if there's any way to run this instruction in CUDA without a lot of overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of integer intrinsics is available in the [documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__INT.html). You can use the `__clz` intrinsic for example to mimic BSR. For BSF, I think `__ffs` should do most of the job.